# Get Swarm node IP address from a container using API?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How to get the Swarm node IP address of just created container, using remote API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relevant container information can be found with `docker inspect <your container>`.

The IP of the node your container is running on can be obtained with

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .Node.IP }}" <your container>
```

Note however, that this might not be the publicly reachable IP address (on an AWS EC2 instance for example, where this would be a private IP).

To get the hostname and port your swarm masters use to reach the node, use

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .Node.Addr }}" <your container>
```